# identifying url for autologging

Tags: java, http-headers, httpclient, web-scraping, autologin

I want to identify the login url for a particular website and autologin.
The view source shows the form tag as follows:

```
<form id="signIn" onsubmit="return false;" action="/f1/logon" method="post">
```

How do i identify the url and pass the requested paramters?

I tried the suggestions below but no help. More suggestions?

Comment: hostname of the site you're connecting to + the value of `action` will get you pretty close. You also need to search the source for the actual username and password fields. Is your question also about how to parse this string with regex, or some similar parsing tool?

Comment: The `onsubmit="return false;"` suggests that the login may be handled by AJAX, or that script obfuscates the login details before submitting the form.

Comment: @normalocity...hostname/f1/logon doesnt show anything in UI. Im not asking about parsing rightnow. I want to find a way to login to the site. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @javaiText:  It seems login is handle by javascript.To be sure about that use firefox `live http header` addon and see what happens when you login manually. If there is javascript involvment you need to use a headless browser like `htmlunit` which can handle javascript.

Comment: You can also add live http header output to your current question for more clearity.

Comment: i hv installed live http header but i dont get much info from there.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and submit the form.  It will tell you what URL was requested and what parameters were passed with it.

Comment: I have downloaded fiddler. How do i trace now?

Comment: @javaiText: Start up Fiddler.  It will display all requests and responses submitted in any browser, so you navigate to the form in your browser and watch the request come up in the Fiddler view.  Then when you click on the request in Fiddler you will see its details.

Answer (score 0):

The form can be submitted from javascript code. Look for using **signIn** element, for example may be javascript,

```
var form = document.getElementById("signIn");
form.action = "<URL>";
form.submit();
```

The another method to get URL and parameters it is browser plugins, like HttpWatch (for IE) or HttpFox (for FireFox). They can monitor request and response.

Comment: I dont see something like you mentioned in javascript.